# how to add history function to retrieve the chat history from pubnub

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to save the chat history in the database. Is there any inbuilt functions for that ?

```
chat.controller('chat', ['Messages', '$scope', function(Messages, $scope) {

// Message Inbox
$scope.chats = {};

Messages.user({id: "support-agent", name: "Support Agent"});

// Receive Messages
Messages.receive(function(message, isPrivate) {

    // isPrivate is always true

    // create a new chat if doesn't exist
    if(!$scope.chats[message.user.id]) {

        $scope.chats[message.user.id] = {
            user: message.user,
            messages: []
        };

    }

    // add messages to the chat
    $scope.chats[message.user.id].messages.push(message);

});

// Send Messages
$scope.send = function(to, text) {

    var message = { 
        to: to,
        data: text,
        user: Messages.user()
    };

    Messages.send(message);

    // because we are sending a message to a user's personal channel,
    // but not subscribing to it we need to keep track of sent messages 
    // ourselves
    $scope.chats[to].messages.push(message);

};

}]);
```

Where to add the history function in the code ?